# Sitecore 8 strange behavior when converting ISO Date to .net DateTime

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore8

I have an item with a field "`Birthday`". The value is "`15/03/1977`" and the raw value is "`19770315T000000`". I took example from [here](http://getfishtank.ca/blog/using-date-and-datetime-fields-in-sitecore)

Now the output of following code is:

```cs
var item = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("{8935CD35-5EAD-4C8E-B85C-E95E9B1ED5C3}");
DateField dateField = (DateField)item.Fields["Birthdate"];
// DateTime object
var date = dateField.DateTime.Date;
 // String
lblTest.Text = date.ToString();
```

**Output**:

```
3/14/1977 12:00:00 AM // Instead of 15 here date is 14
```

If I format the string to "`dd-MM-yyyy`":

```cs
 lblTest.Text = date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

**Output**

```
 14-03-1977
```

I don't know why I have this difference, the date saved is `15/03/1977` and the output is `14-03-1977`.

And second question is, in above code  `var date = dateField.DateTime.Date;` I am assigning `.Date` to variable `date` but in the output I still see the time if no format is provided. I am talking about this `lblTest.Text = date.ToString();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be because of the timezone added to the DateTime field raw values in Sitecore 8.

Similar problem described in this blog post: 
[Sitecore 8 ServerTimeZone – my dates are all wrong](https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2015/04/16/sitecore-8-servertimezone-my-dates-are-all-wrong/)

The new format contains `Z` at the end (e.g. `20160907T120740Z`) which is part of the ISO 8601 datetime standard for UTC times and indicates that that time is UTC.

I'm not 100% sure if this will help you but you can try:

```cs
Sitecore.DateUtil.ToServerTime(dateField.DateTime).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

> And second question is, in above code  var date = dateField.DateTime.Date; I am assigning .Date to variable date but in the output I still see the time if no format is provided. I am talking about this lblTest.Text = date.ToString();

The System.DateTime.Date property is still a DateTime object, just with the default value for the time fragment. You need to apply formatting if you want to lose the time fragment.